# MapKit poor scrolling performance with Apple Maps in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, ios6, mapkit

I am writing an app which displays a simple Apple Map across most of the screen. However, when I compare the speed of scrolling, there is a significant slow-down comparative to the native Apple Maps which come with iOS 6.

In my investigation of why, I noticed that the Facebook App (which also uses Apple Maps), the same performance hit is present.

This is most noticeable on iPhone 4 with iOS 6.

Does anyone know of a special view-related performance enhancing step or set of steps which I need to take to increase performance? I would like my maps to move as fluidly as the Apple Maps app.

Comment: I do have the same issue but until know there is nothing to fix this. Very bad!! it is very weird to see that apple's maps app don't have this performance issues.

Comment: We also have issues in our own app. Been trying several things, but no solution so far. Scrolling is relatively OK when dragging the map around, but as soon as I let go and the map should move on due to inertia, movement becomes very choppy.

Comment: Noticed this myself in a 3rd party app, but I blamed the developer. Now when I create an empty project with a MKMapView I can see it has major performance issues when decelerating even on latest devices. Let's all submit a [bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Apple's native app uses MKWorldView which is private API

Comment: Do you have a delegate or and annotations on the map?

Comment: I've seen this happen, the cache of the map isnt that great. try clearing it and see if that helps here is a code bit to help:     NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
[sharedCache release];

Comment: Did you solve this? Maybe someone going to WWDC can discuss with Apple. Can you upload a demo project?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, and it looks like it could be due to having Development enabled on the device.

On the [Apple Dev Forums](http://developer.apple.com/devforums/) I posted to ask about this for my problems ([my post](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/185603?tstart=0)) and someone rightly reminded me that a lot of developers have been complaining about sluggish development devices.

So I went to the Organizer and Ignored my device from there, removing it as development enabled. I restarted the device and sure enough my `MKMapView` was a lot snappier. It was still sluggish at times, but the performance improved significantly.

Try it out for your device and see if you notice a difference.

[image]

Comment: It didn't work for me. The performance of the map while scrooling was the same before and after I disabled it as you recommend on the screen. Also, building it in a Release mode didn't help.